# How can I implement Schema.org on my Drupal 6 site?

Tags: 6

I can't seem to find a straight-forward answer to implementing this - http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/introducing-schemaorg-search-engines.html - on my Drupal site.

I've found lots of Drupal discussion about microformats, RDF and RDFa, as well as support for RDF in Drupal 7 core, but I can't find a module that will help me to take advantage of Schema.org in Drupal 6.

As a non-developer, how can I easily start to work with Schema.org on my Drupal 6 site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine that this isn't going to be possible anytime soon, if at all.

> The module leverages the native RDFa layer present in Drupal 7 core.
>   Doing the same in Drupal 6 is impossible or would involve a lot of
>   patching. In any case, I won't have any resource to work on a Drupal 6
>   version of this module.

Taken from [here](http://drupal.org/node/1210550#comment-4710368).

Although this is in a post requesting a backport of the schema.org module, the reasoning behind why the maintainer can't do it would apply to anyone else.

Comment: How disappointing :/

Presumably I'm best off compromising with just an implementation of RDF? I understand there might be some modules for that.

Comment: Yup - http://drupal.org/project/rdf.  It's only in alpha though =\

Answer (score 4):

Anyone coming across this looking for this in Drupal 7 (I know the question is for D6), see the [Schema.org](http://drupal.org/project/schemaorg) module. Using this module sites administrators can specify what schema.org terms they want to associate with their content types (e.g. Art Gallery, House, Event, Person, etc.) and their fields (description, participants, etc).

Although this project is syntax agnostic, the schema.org types and properties selected by the site administrator will be used as part of the native Drupal 7 RDFa markup.

You can also use the [Microdata](http://drupal.org/project/microdata) module. Microdata is a module which takes care of embedding schema.org terms in HTML per the microdata spec. Core does it via the RDFa 1.0 spec. There is a UI for schema.org in microdata so that it does not have to depend on other modules for the UI (Drupal core does not include such UI).